# Doctrine 1.2 must have at least one field selected Error.but one is actually selected

Tags: php, doctrine

i've been banging my head against the wall over the past hour about this Exception :

> The root class of the query (alias b) must have at least one field selected

on a small school hotel booking project here is the part of the schema concerned

```
RoomType:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  tableName: room_type
  columns:
    name: string(100)
    number_of_bed: integer

Room:
  tableName: room
  columns:
    id:
      type: string(36)
      primary: true
    room_number: integer
    price: decimal
  relations:
    RoomType:
      class: RoomType
      local: type_id
      foreign: id

RoomBooking:
  tableName: roombooking
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    id:
      type: string(36)
      primary: true
      room_id: string(36)
      checkin_date: date
      checkout_date: date
      is_cancelled: boolean
  relations:
    Room:
      class: Room
      local: room_id
      foreign: id
```

i tripped out certain field for sake of simplicity and having short post.So basically i wanted to query for the total, the type of rooms booked each day of a certain month.i wanted things simple so for now i assumed booking are just for 24 hours so for now i'm just looking at checkin date.here is the query

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create ()
->select("SUM(COUNT(b.id)), b.checkin_date as DATE, t.name")
->from ("Hotel_Model_RoomBooking b" )
->leftJoin("b.Room r")
->leftJoin("r.RoomType t")
->where ("b.checkin_date > ? AND b.checkin_date < ?", array ($first, $last))
->groupBy("b.checkin_date, t.name");

$result = $q->fetchArray ();
```

`b.checkin_date` is one field of the root class so i have this and `b.id` selected, and up to now i can't figure it out.What do you think? what am i doing wrong here? thanks for reading and thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Doctrine and I had the same problem. Removing the alias makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

It's because all fields from root element are aliased - it's a bug (it's reported in Doctrine's Jira but I can't find it).

```
->select("SUM(COUNT(b.id)), b.checkin_date as DATE, t.name")
```

As You can see that both, b.id and b.checkin_date, have an alias:
b.id will be sum , checkin_date is DATE :)
The simplest fixture for Your problem would be:

```
->select("SUM(COUNT(b.id)), b.checkin_date as DATE, b.checkin_date, t.name")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all of primary_key on ur database That's your choice.
for example :

```
->select('(pol.quantity * pol.price) as actual_material_cost')
        ->addSelect('p.project_id')
        ->addSelect('pol.purchase_order_line_id')
        ->addSelect('ri.requisition_item_id')
        ->addSelect('pt.project_task_id')
        ->addSelect('polri.purchase_order_line_req_item_id')
        ->from('PurchaseOrderLines pol')
        ->leftJoin('pol.PurchaseOrderLineReqItems polri')
        ->leftJoin('polri.RequisitionItems ri')
        ->leftJoin('ri.ProjectTasks pt')
        ->leftJoin('pt.Projects p')
        ->where('p.project_id = ?' , $project_id);
```